# Go store new value using a value receiver

Tags: go

It's canonical to store a new value given the method has a pointer receiver. For example:

```
type MyTime time.Time

func (mt *MyTime) Change(other time.Time) {
    *mt = MyTime(other)
}
```

But is it possible **without** the pointer receiver?

```
type MyTime time.Time

func (mt MyTime) Change(other time.Time) {
    // ???
}
```

Perhaps using `reflect` or the `atomic` package?

Comment: If you want to update it in pass by value return it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When you call a method with a value receiver, the method is called using a copy of the receiver. Any modifications performed on the receiver will be done on that copy. In other words:

```
x:=myTime{}
x.ValueReceiverFunc()
```

is equivalent to:

```
x:=myTime{}
y:=x
y.ValueReceiverFunc()
```